# Reconnecting to google cloud datalab; notebook seems to be frozen

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I setted up a google cloud datalab vm on google cloud following their instructions [on the official page](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstarts). I also created the datalab vm using the google cloud sdk on my local computer and the problem was the same using both ways.

Both ways I could open the notebook, run my code and everything looked good in the beginning. However, if I close the browser windows, computer turns to sleep mode or connection break, I cannot reconnect properly. My code runs for couple of hours producing output. When I reconnect I only see the output from the last autosave but no new data is produced and the notebook is not responding.

From the google cloud platform I can see that the datalab vm instance is running on full cpu power so it seems like the kernel is running but the notebook is not connecting properly. I'm using windows 10 with chrome.